# Помогите создать корректную структуру и функцию чтобы я мог получить отдельные значения из JSON объектав golang?

Tags: golang

Я пытаюсь написать функцию, которая будет принимать закодированную строку, отправлять запрос в службу jsonrpc, затем мне нужно выбрать определенные данные (ask: assets: interface) и создать новые переменные

Как я могу создать структуру для такого объекта:

```
{
  "ask": {
  "amount": 0,
  "assets": [
    {
      "assetref": "74-266-27408",
      "name": "USD",
      "qty": 5000
    }
  ]
  },
  "cancomplete": true,
  "candisable": true,
  "complete": false,
  "offer": {
  "amount": 0,
  "assets": [
    {
      "assetref": "73-266-61482",
      "name": "BTC",
      "qty": 1
    }
  ]
  },
  "requiredfee": 0
}
```

И сделать функцию, которая возвращает структурированный объект:

```
type Order struct {
    Ask map[string]ask
    Cancomplete bool
    Candisable bool
    Complete bool
    Offer map[string]offer
    Requiredfee float64
}

type ask struct {
    Ammount float64
    Assets map[string]assets
}

type offer struct {
    Ammount float64
    Assets map[string]assets
}

type assets struct {
    Assetref string
    Name string
    Qty float64
}

func DecodeOrder(datahex string) (*Order){
    //order, _ := rpcClient.Call("decoderawexchange", datahex)
    //var d *Order
    //err := order.GetObject(&d)
    //if err != nil || d == nil {
    //  panic(err)
    //}
    //
    //f := d.Ask.Name

    var d *Order
    err := rpcClient.CallFor(&d, "decoderawexchange", datahex)

    if err != nil || d == nil {
        // handle error
    }

    fmt.Print(d)
    return d

}
```

Сейчас это возвращает

Помогите создать корректную структуру и функцию чтобы я мог получить значения ask:assets:name:interface и offer:assets:name:interface

Ссылка на используемый rpc client - https://github.com/ybbus/jsonrpc

Comment: Сейчас что возвращает?

Comment: Зачем у вас `Assets` -- мапа? Должен же быть слайс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен с помощью сгенерированной структуры https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

```
type Order struct {
    Ask struct {
        Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
        Assets []struct {
            Assetref string `json:"assetref"`
            Name     string `json:"name"`
            Qty      float64    `json:"qty"`
        } `json:"assets"`
    } `json:"ask"`
    Cancomplete bool `json:"cancomplete"`
    Candisable  bool `json:"candisable"`
    Complete    bool `json:"complete"`
    Offer       struct {
        Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
        Assets []struct {
            Assetref string `json:"assetref"`
            Name     string `json:"name"`
            Qty      float64    `json:"qty"`
        } `json:"assets"`
    } `json:"offer"`
    Requiredfee float64 `json:"requiredfee"`
}
```